# Datatables - filter sql query by bootstrap-datepicker values

Tags: php, sql-server, datatables, bootstrap-datepicker

I have 2 bootstrap datepickers(#start,#end) and a Datatable which returns 150.000 rows from MS SQL Server via PHP.I want by default the start date to be 7 days earlier nad the end date to be Today.

I need to find a way to filter the Sql Query (in a PHP file) with WHERE condition between #start and #end datepicker values.If i use no filter the returned JSON is 60 MBs which freezes the browser and consequently i can't even filter the Datatable in the client.

I have already used  $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push to filter the Datatable on the client and it works ,but i want to filter the JSON output from the Sql Query before it returns to the browser.

How can i dynamically pass these date values via ajax.url in the Sql Query which is in the backend PHP file?

```
 var curdate = moment().subtract(7, 'day').toDate();

 $( '#end' ).datepicker( 'setDate', new Date() );
 $( '#start' ).datepicker( 'setDate', curdate );

 var start = $('#start').val();
 var end   = $('#end').val();

 $("#start").datepicker({ language: 'el', autoclose: true,              
          onchangeDate: function () { 

        var start = $('#start').val();
        table.ajax.url('queries.php?q=employees_full&start='+start'&end='+end); //do i miss a + here??
        //table.ajax.reload();
          table.draw(); }});

 $("#end").datepicker({ language: 'el', autoclose: true,
          onchangeDate: function () {  
 var end = $('#end').val();
      table.ajax.url('queries.php?q=employees_full&start='+start'&end='+end); //do i miss a + here??
       //table.ajax.reload();table.draw(); }});


 $('#start, #end').change(function () {
       //table.ajax.url('queries.php?q=employees_full&start='+start+'&end='+end);
        // table.ajax.reload();            
           table.draw();          
        });
```

1)What is the difference between table.ajax.reload() and table.draw ?

2)i also get an error in JSON output"Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string." .Probably the #start datepicker value is undefined,i don't know why??

3)Is the order of the commands right?

4)The dates in the Datepicker are in Format dd/mm/yyy but in the Sql Query queries.php?q=employees_full are in Format yyyy-mm-dd.I use prepared statements and have used the following:

```
  (CONVERT(date,SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, ?, 100), 4, 3) +SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, ?, 100), 1, 3)+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, ?, 100), 7, 4)))
```

AND

```
  $stmt = sqlsrv_prepare( $conn, $sql , array(&$_GET["start"],&$_GET["start"],&$_GET["start"]));
```

The Datatable is :

```
 var table = $('#example').DataTable({

//"serverSide": true,
"ajax" : { url: 'queries.php?q=employees_full&start='+start'&end='+end ,
           dataType: "json",
            dataSrc: '' },
"order": [[ 5, "desc" ]],     
"autoWidth": true,
"deferRender": true ,
"columns": [
      { "data": "username", "title": "Username" }]
```

### });

EDIT 15/3/19

After a lot of research,i ended up to this.

I initialize the bootstrap datepickers and with the ajax.data option i pass the parameters(date objects) to the php Sql Query.

1)Is it better to pass the parameters as date objects instead of strings so that the conversion and comparison in the Sql Query is easier?

2)Should the initialisation of the Datepickers be before or after the Datatable?

3)Should i use 2 events .change and .on('changedate') for the datepickers so that both values to have been set before the initialisation of the datatable?

When i load the page , I get error  : input1 is not defined

and after that when i pick different dates,i get TypeError: table is undefined.
I still can't find the right order of the commands i should use.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
    var curdate = moment().subtract(7, 'day').toDate();

    $("#start,#end").datepicker({ language: 'el', autoclose: true});
    $( '#end' ).datepicker( 'setDate', new Date() );
    $( '#start'  ).datepicker( 'setDate', curdate );

    $('#start, #end').datepicker({ language: 'el', autoclose: true}).change(function () {

    //var thisval = this.value; //this.val--> undefined
     var start= $( '#apo' ).datepicker( 'getUTCDate' );// returns datetime object
     var end= $( '#ews' ).datepicker( 'getUTCDate' );// returns datetime object

     var input1={ startdate: $( '#start' ).datepicker( 'getUTCDate' ), 
                     enddate: $( '#end' ).datepicker( 'getUTCDate' ) };

       //table.ajax.url("queries.php?q=employees_full"); //do i need this?
       //table.ajax.reload(); //or table.draw();
       });      

  var table = $('#example4').DataTable({
                "ajax" : { url: "queries.php?q=employees_full" ,
                           dataType: "json",
                           dataSrc: '' ,
                           data: input1 },
                                       ......});
```

In the PHP Sql Query queries.php?q=employees_full i prepare the statement with

```
   ... WHERE alldates.alldate >= (CONVERT(date, ?))  and alldates.alldate <= (CONVERT(date, ?))
```

and

```
   $stmt = sqlsrv_prepare( $conn, $sql , array(&$_POST["startdate"],&$_POST["enddate"]));
```

What am i missing?

Comment: What you're trying to achieve is called several side processing: https://datatables.net/reference/option/serverSide. In this mode, certain parameters that define sorting are sent to the server using AJAX-calls, you need to catch them server side and prepare corresponding data chunk.

Comment: You mean serverside processing.I know that,but i think i can achieve the same in the frontend.I am trying to find out what i am missing in my code.

Comment: Yes, I meant 'server side' (answered from smartphone). Since you're asking a bunch of questions, it's hard to cope with them all at once. To me it doesn't make sense to load a library and write your own lump of code to implement those same features.

Comment: You don't need to do those substrings in SQL, you may try `STR_TO_DATE ()` function in MySQL to adjust date string to proper format.

Comment: I understand,but i am not doing anything complex i think,i am just trying to pass datepicker values as get parameters in ajax.url('queries.php?q=employees_full&start='+start+'&end='+end).My code simply needs some modifications-adjustments.

Comment: Since, you're not using `serverSide: true` `. draw()` method will not work for you, you're going to need to retrieve each new data portion upon each sorting via ajax call. So, `ajax.reload()` is proper choice.

Comment: Your task is pretty much complex, in fact. If you could break it into smaller chunks, chances to get relevant help would be much bigger

Comment: Thanks for the help